# Is it normal to have conflicts during applying a git patch?

Tags: git, format-patch, git-am

I have two repos let's say `main repo` and `copy repo`, and they have to get synced using patches. Their `master` branches are synced and I apply patches from `main repo`-`dev` branch on `copy repo`. And after creating a patch and applying it on `copy repo`, I merge `dev` branch into the `master` on `main repo` to keep them synced.

I have created the patch file on `main repo` using:

```
git format-patch origin/master..origin/develop --stdout > ../patches/patch-001.patch
```

and when I try to apply this patch on `copy repo` using:

```
git am -3 --ignore-space-change patch-001.patch
```

I get `Patch failed at 0002 ...` and I have to resolve conflicts for almost every commit in the patch file.

The question is that is it **normal** to have conflicts during applying a patch? I have done this before but no such problems happened.

Resolving this amount of conflicts (for about 50 commits) is a very hard and confusing process. I'm using the *PyCharm* itself to resolve conflicts for every patch failure but still hard. Is there any easier way to do this?

Why these conflicts happen? Is it because I have `merges` between those commits?

Comment: "Normal" as in "possible"? Yes it is.

Comment: If the two repositories have diverged, there will be conflicts if they both have made changes to the same regions in the same files. If they have not, you are doing something wrong with the patch.

Comment: @tripleee I don't make any changes to `copy repo` and it updates only using these patches. Applying the patch is like creating it from `master`..`dev` changes and applying it to `master` on the same repo because `master` branches are the same on both repo.

Comment: Thanks @RomainValeri. I know it's possible but how often? I want to know if I'm doing anything wrong that causes these conflicts? Is applying the patch like merging two branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's neither "normal" nor "abnormal".  It is what it is.  If your white cat gets a slow-growing skin cancer on an ear-tip, it's easily removed via simple surgery.  Is skin cancer on your light-skinned-cat's ear "normal"?  It's not *ab*normal, if your cat goes outside: UV on low-melanin-content skin cells causes mutations, and sometimes those lead to basal cell cancer.  You can keep your cat indoors (this is generally advised for most house cats anyway) but that's no guarantee that he *won't* get skin cancer on a pink ear-tip or nose either.<sup>1</sup>

> Why [do] these conflicts happen?

When Git is doing a merge, Git finds *three* input files.  When you apply a patch, Git may choose to do a merge, if there's an `index:` line in the patch.<sup>2</sup>  The `index` line tells Git what the *original file* was, to which the patch applies.  Git can then apply the patch—which applies only to the original file at this point—*to* that original file to come up with "their file".

Git now has the same information it would use for any merge: the original file, your version of the file with *your* changes, and *their* version of the file with *their* changes.  Git can now compare your changes to their changes, to see if they overlap.

If what *they* changed is *independent* of what *you* changed, Git will be able to combine these changes.  For instance, suppose they fixed the spelling of the word `speeling` on line 10, and you didn't.  Suppose that, instead, you fixed the lack of a copyright notice by adding 40 lines of copyright notice at the top of the file.  Git will be able to see that the `speeling` line is now line 50, rather than line 10, and that it should apply their fix.  Git will apply their fix and all will be well.

But if you *also* fixed the `speeling` line *and some other words on the same line*, Git doesn't know whether to take *your* fix or *their* fix.  So Git now complains of a merge conflict on this line.  That's because your changes affect the *same lines* of the base file that their changes affect.  Git doesn't know which ones to use.

Is that normal?  It is if you both changed the same lines of the same files.  It all depends on what lines "you" changed, and what lines "they" changed, based on which *common starting version* of the file you both *started from*.  It doesn't if you got those changes from someone else somewhere along the way: as long as *they* **didn't** have those changes in the version *they* started from, so that "your" changes (which include someone else's changes) and their changes *overlap*, you'll get a conflict.

Note that you get a conflict even if your changes and their changes don't exactly overlap.  For instance, if they change lines 5-through-8 and you change line 9, these changes "touch at the edge" ("abut", to use the fancy word) and Git will call *that* a conflict too.

---

<sup>1</sup>I had a solid-black kitty that got some kind of cancer on her nose, when I lived in Utah.  So even plenty of melanin isn't a guarantee against this, though it helps.  She had a pretty decent life though, making it to "senior kitty" status.  Her sister died the previous year from kidney failure, so it's likely she might not have lasted much longer even if she'd made it through the cancer-removal surgery.  Nose surgery is a much bigger deal than ear-tip clipping, unfortunately.

<sup>2</sup>If the patch *lacks* an index line, Git *can't* do a three-way merge.  But this just means that a patch that doesn't apply *fails*, rather than trying a merge; you'll need the `--reject` flag, and you will have to hand-edit the patch result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @torek. I think this is a good explanation to understand conflicts.